# Automating installing Ubuntu Core, without serial port and without signing into account

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-core, automation

I am currently busy with a project for standardizing the processes surrounding an embedded device we export as a product. On this device we wish to use Ubuntu Core (UC). However, part of this standardization is automating processes such as installing UC.

From the tutorials (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-core-on-raspberry-pi#4-boot-ubuntu-core) and experience we gather that there is a considerable degree of manual labour that is necessary for installing UC. For example, we would need to "enter the email address that is connected to your SSO account" for every single device that we send to our clients (this would also require to establish a serial connection and user i/o devices). You can probably see how installing a large number of these IoT devices would be a costly process we would like to avoid.

An idea we thought of was flashing the needed ssh key / certificate onto the ROM of our device in order to avoid this manual process of validating our device and establishing a connection with Canonical. Is there a way to pre-install valid ssh public keys to avoid manual installing? Or could we write a script that handles this process automatically?

Any input is very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that the ONLY reason you would need to enter any sort of email address on the device would be to enable logging into the device. Once you flash UC on (with any pre-installed snaps) the thing will connect to the internet and start automatically updating as necessary. So can you expand your question to cover how the device will be used without giving anything important away? Do YOU need to be able to gain access to all the devices you sell, or do your customers? Or neither? If neither, you might be able to ignore the "login" capability altogether unless you actually want to disable it.

Comment: How to customize Ubuntu Core: https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/custom-images